# Real time application on Microsoft Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, message-queue, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

I'm working on a real-time application and building it on Azure.

The idea is that every user reports something about himself and all the other users should see it immediately (they poll the service every seconds or so for new info)

My approach for now was using a Web Role for a WCF REST Service where I'm doing all the writing to the DB (SQL Azure) without a Worker Role so that it will be written immediately.

I've come think that maybe using a Worker Role and a Queue to do the writing might be much more scalable, but might interfere with the real-time side of the service. (The worker role might not take the job immediately from the queue)

Is it true? How should I go about this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that the queue will add a bit of latency, you'll be able to scale out the number of Worker Role instances to handle the sheer volume of messages.

You can also optimize queue-reading by getting more than one message at a time. Since a single queue has a scalability target of 500 TPS, this lets you go well beyond 500 messages per second on reads.

You might look into a Cache for buffering the latest user updates, so when polling occurs, your service reads from cache instead of SQL Azure. That might help as the volume of information increases.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at SignalR, it does not support farm scenarios out-of-the-box, but should be able to work with the use of either internal endpoint calls to update every instance, using the Azure Service Bus, or using the AppFabric Cache. This way you get a Push scenario rather than a Pull scenario, thus you don't have to poll your endpoints for potential updates.